# What is the Euler-Lagrange equation of this function?

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

Consider $$I(y)=\int_a^b g(x)\sqrt{1+(y'(x))^2}dx$$
where $g$ is a know differentiable funtion of $x$, $y'$is also a function of $x$.

In this case, it only has one independent variable $x$, so I wonder is it the same as the case where you have several independent variables, if not, how to derive the EL equation.

Comment: The only function varied is *y(x)* then? what is your conjecture?

Comment: Actually the form you require is given on the Wikipedia page for the Euler equations. Several functions of a single variable with a single derivative.

Comment: @CosmasZachos there is another function g(x), so why is y(x) the only function varied?

Comment: @Kyle. Because the statement of the question says *known* differential function, so  I gather  you do  not need it adjusted/varied in his extremization. But that's precisely the reassurance I asked for, isn't it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $I(y)=\int_a^b g(x)\sqrt{1+(y'(x))^2}dx$
>   where *g* is a *known* differentiable function of *x*.

If I am to trust you actually mean your statement, then the only function to vary in the extremization is *y(x)*. In that case, with the boundary variations vanishing, the variational equation results out of the $\delta y'$ variation to be just
$$
0=\partial_x \frac{g y'}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}= \frac{g' y'+ g y''}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}  - \frac{g y'' (y')^2  }{(1+(y')^2)\sqrt{1+(y')^2}} \\ = \frac{g' y' }{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}  + \frac{g   y''}{(1+(y')^2)\sqrt{1+(y')^2}} ~~.
$$

Now you do realize the solution for *y'* in terms of *g* reverses these two very steps!
$$
\frac{ y'}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}= c/g(x) ~ .
$$